# BAT file to replace string in two lines

Tags: batch-file, replace

I'm writting a script in Windows, a .BAT file, to replace:

Note that there is an ENTER, I mean the string is in two lines. And looks more complicated now: after the 2 double quotes there are 2 blank spaces and then the "ENTER"

```
""  
"2014
```

So, something like: (double quote)(double quote)(space)(space)(newline)(double quote)2014

I'm having problems with this. This is how the script looks like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=FILE_IN_CSV.csv
set OUTTEXTFILE=222.csv
set SEARCHTEXT=^"^"^"2014
set REPLACETEXT=^"^"^"4
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

    echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: adding source text example. See that there are 3 (not 2!) black spaces at the end of each line.

```
"2014091810000076";"Question about folder sizes";"2014-09-18 12:10:20";"2014-09-25 17:33:15";"Resolt Sistemes";"jbgsfnam";"Sistemes::Altres";"STFD";"peticions";""   
"2014091910000109";"Error opening word files with office 2013";"2014-09-19 09:50:07";"2014-09-25 14:27:59";"Resolt TRO";"yerttom";"Qualitat::Altres";"STFD";"peticions";""
```

I just need to delete the 20 at the beginning of each line, but not the others 20 in the middle of lines.

Comment: so you are having problems? care to elaborate?

Comment: Hi, I just add some source text as example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q6288377.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%a
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 ECHO(^"!line:~3!
 endlocal
 )
)>newfile.txt
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q6288377.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%a
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 IF "!line:~1,2!"=="20" (ECHO(^"!line:~3!) else (echo(%%a)
 endlocal
 )
)>newfile2.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

It's incredibly difficult to solve a problem stated as "my code doesn't do what I want it to do" without an clear indication of desired outcome.

Your problem appears to be to delete the "20" in columns 2 and 3 of the text file (I changed the name to suit my system.)

The code above assumes that **every** line of your file starts `"`. The first part arbitrarily deletes whatever characters are in columns 2 and 3, creating `newfile.txt`. The second selects only those lines which have `20` in columns 2 and 3 and deletes those columns, leaving other lines alone and creates `newfile2.txt`.

You have changed the requirement from ""<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Newline</kbd>"2014 to 3 terminal spaces, No indication of whether the first line is an exception (it wouldn't be preceded by ""<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Newline</kbd>) and so the above may not be applicable. No idea whether the presence of the sequences is significant or not - and in all probability, a utility like `sed` is more suited to the task (Google is your friend)

---

[edit for extended question]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%u IN (q6288377*.txt) DO (
(
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%%u") DO (
 SET line=%%a
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 ECHO(^"!line:~3!
 endlocal
 )
)>%%~nu.xtx
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. File produced would be *samename*.xtx. Don't try to overwrite the existing files directly.

You could also create new files in a different directory by prefixing `%%~nu.xtx` with a directory name, eg "c:\some random\directory\%%~nu.xtx" - "enclose in quotes" if the directory or filenames contain separators (like spaces). The `~nu` means "the name of `%%u` - see **for /?** from the prompt for more information.

It's always easier to solve an entire problem than to approach it piecemeal. A full description may influence the method used.

Comment: This code is working perfectly, thanks!

Let me ask you 1 last question: is it possible to modify this script to apply this to all the CSV files in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can't work ever.

1. Command `for` processes text always line by line. Therefore it is not possible to get 2 lines as string into an environment variable and modify this string.
2. Paragraph symbol `¶` (code value B6 hexadecimal) is just a placeholder when viewing a text file with showing line endings. The CSV file contains carriage return (0D) and line-feed (0A) which command `for` interprets always as delimiter character independent on what you specify.

It would be better to use a text editor like UltraEdit or Notepad++ or Sublime Text to do the replace in the file. It is not even necessary to run a regular expression replace in those editors. But using as search string the Perl regular expression `""\s+"2014` and as replace string `"""4` would result in the modification you want.

There are also console applications written for replacing strings in files. Take a look at [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034/3074564)

Searching for `""  \r\n"2014` and replacing it with `"""4` in the file using only standard commands is nevertheless possible using the code below.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "INTEXTFILE=FILE_IN_CSV.csv"

if not exist "%INTEXTFILE%" goto EndBatch

set "OUTTEXTFILE=%TEMP%\csv_replace.tmp"
if exist "%OUTTEXTFILE%" del "%OUTTEXTFILE%"

set "FirstLine="
set "EndFirstLine=""  "
set "BeginSecondLine="2014"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%INTEXTFILE%") do (
    set "Line=%%A"
    if not "!FirstLine!"=="" (
        if "!Line:~0,5!"=="!BeginSecondLine!" (
            set "FirstLine=!FirstLine!"!Line:~4!"
            echo !FirstLine!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
            set "Line="
        ) else (
            echo !FirstLine!  >>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
        )
        set "FirstLine="
    )
    if not "!Line!"=="" (
        if "!Line:~-4!"=="!EndFirstLine!" (
            set "FirstLine=!Line:~0,-2!"
        ) else (
            echo !Line!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
        )
    )
)

if exist "%OUTTEXTFILE%" (
    copy "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%" >nul
    del "%OUTTEXTFILE%"
)

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Empty lines are removed by this batch file, too. This cannot be avoided as command `for` ignores empty lines on parsing the file.

Comment: This script is not working for me. I edit the initial post with a code example. Thanks!

Comment: So you just want to trim trailing spaces and remove 2nd and 3rd character (century) from all lines. That is something completely different than what was described originally. I thought, there are line breaks within a field value in the CSV file and therefore it is necessary to concatenate two lines to a single line under certain conditions. So I wrote a completely wrong code for what is really needed. An input and output example is always best to describe such tasks.

Comment: Yes, you are right sorry. I forget to post an example of source text.